# Meteor JS: How to use Spacebars to display contents inside an array retrieved from Meteor Collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

I have a collection:

```
MenuItems = new Mongo.Collection('menu_items');
```

and I also have an array:

```
var arrayToInsert = ['Gemstone', 'Rings'];
```

I then insert this array into the collection via:

```
MenuItems.insert(arrayToInsert);
```

The resulting document inside my mongodb as shown in RoboMongo is:

```
{
    "_id" : "yRXmFGxLCZXLf9Ynh",
    "0" : "Gemstone",
    "1" : "Rings"
}
```

In my Template Helper I have:

```
menuItems: function(){
    return MenuItems.find();
  },
```

In my .html file I do this:

```
{{#each menuItems}}
  {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

But I only get this output:

```
[object Object]
```

How do I use Spacebars to iterate through this array of data so I may get it to display 'Gemstone' and 'Rings'????

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, {{this[1]}}  doesn't work....{{this[0]}} also does not work....

Comment: oops its {{this.[1]}} forgot that the result is an array of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the array to represent the menu items value, you should insert them into the collection like this :

```
arrayToInsert.forEach(function(menuItem){
  MenuItems.insert({
    label: menuItem
  });
});
```

Then you can display the menu items in your template :

JS

```
Template.menu.helpers(function(){
  menuItems: function(){
    return MenuItems.find();
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="menu">
  <ul>
    {{#each menuItems}}
      <li>{{label}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

If you want to store the array as part of the collection documents, use this code :

JS

```
MenuItems.insert({
  items:arrayToInsert
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="menu">
  {{#each menuItems}}
    <ul>
      {{#each items}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Ok, so with its current form of insertion e.g. MenuItems.insert(arrayToInsert); there is no way of displaying the data using spacebars??? It really has to be assigned to a 'key' like ur example above???   Thank you

Comment: Assigning the array to a key is a lot easier to manipulate, you won't have to deal with the `this.[index]` syntax.